# Multipart emails — is there a mime type that ONLY MS Outlook will open / parse?

Tags: email, outlook, html-email

I'm working on emails that have to be both responsive (mobile / desktop) and friendly across a wide range of clients. For the most part we have pretty simple designs but there are a couple of places I'm getting bogged down.

I'm honestly at the point where I'd rather just create a totally separate MS-Word / Outlook-friendly design, using Outlook as the creator — it'd be easier and faster than trying to develop the whole d*mn thing for every client. Does anyone know if there's a way to hack mime types — so Outlook and related clients will open the outlook-friendly part, and other clients will open the HTML part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to hack mime types, just wrap your outlook version in
`<!--[if gte mso 9]> outlook tables <![endif]-->` and your non outlook version in `<!--[if !mso]><!--> other tables <!--<![endif]-->` and send the whole thing as one html file.

You can do things this way, but i'll warn you that even outlook's html email tools don't always show up right in outlook. I'd recommend biting the bullet and learning how to make desktop code that works in the MSO versions of outlook ('07, '10, '13).

Pro tip for outlook compatibility: use padding on `<td>`s for spacing and nest tables when `padding-top` gives you issues in outlook 13.

Comment: Yes -- thanks for the feedback (and your helpful comments on other related questions). I played with the approach you suggested here [conditional MSO checks] and it *almost* worked... except for *@#$ outlook.com, which of course ignored everything in the tags.

Comment: ah yes, that is a pain. outlook.com does eat comment enclosed tags :(

that's the main reason for not doing the conditionals except where it's totally necessary.

There is still hope though. If you're running into layout issues in outlook with your base code, you can give classes to your problem cells, wrap a style tag at the top of your body in the MSO conditional, and give those classes `!important` rules to override your inline css.